# Drupal commerce add text to price

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-commerce

I'm trying to add a simple line off text next to the price in my Drupal Commerce solution.

Seems quite simple but i'm lost where to start. Here is my problem summarised:

- Drupal commerce doesn't use templates but views for every page so i want to edit the view
- All views contain a rendered entity most off the time a product list
- I can add fields to the product list display but these are all fields that are editable on the product page.

So i'm wondering is there a way to add a simple chunk off text (or HTML) to the product list?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide an example? You need a static html text or dynamic? Also, this text will be inside the price formatatter (BAD idea) or outside (acceptable)?

Comment: I'm trying to add a message and a log in link next to (every) price. Something like: Please register or log in for your individual price.

The text should be hidden after someone is logged in. Or maybe changed for another text. I've seen the option to create a custom field with the display suite. But I don't know how to use this on the product page.

Comment: Take a look at the documentation first for [Commerce](http://www.drupalcommerce.org/user-guide/products) and [Display Suite](https://drupal.org/node/644662). They have all the information that you need.